# loop array of objects in meteor using jade

Tags: meteor, pug

When using blaze and handlebars, I can loop through an array of objects as follow:

```
{{#each cars}}
    <p>{{color}}, {{brand}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

How can I do this with [jade](https://github.com/mquandalle/meteor-jade)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some choices:

```
each cars
  p #{color}, #{brand}
```

or

```
each cars
  p {{color}}, {{brand}}
```

or

```
each cars
  p
    | You can also do this:
    | #{color}, {{brand}}
```