# Each loop explained?

Tags: javascript, pug

Assuming `person` is a javascript object that has `firstname` & `lastname`, in an **each** loop in jade (pug) template how do I render something like :

```
<li>
     <div>{person.firstname} ({person.lastname})</div>
</li>
```

Below is what I got so far but it's kinda confusing me with the equal sign in the official documentation and couldn't find any example where the each loop uses multiple attributes of the `person` object through loop.

```
each person in persons
  li
    div 
      = person.firstname
      = person.email
```

The parenthesis are needed for the `person.lastname` and not a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who struggled  : [loop array of objects in meteor using jade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799919/loop-array-of-objects-in-meteor-using-jade)

Way much easier & clearer than the provided syntax with "=" at https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html